# FBSDKLoginManager loginWithReadPermissions

Tags: ios, facebook

```
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"]
                    fromViewController:self
                               handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
                                   if (error) {
                                       // Process error
                                       NSLog(@"error");
                                   }
                                   else if (result.isCancelled) {
                                       // Handle cancellations
                                       NSLog(@"is cancelled");
                                   }
                                   else {
                                       // If you ask for multiple permissions at once, you
                                       // should check if specific permissions missing
                                       if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"]) {
                                           // Do work
                                       }
                                   }

                               }];
```

This is just a basic login request.  When I run this in the simulator, it works, but when I run it on a device, it brings up a Safari dialog that says "Login to your Facebook account to connect to xxxApp".  I put in my credentials (I am the admin on the Facebook app) but the dialog just gets cleared and sits there. If I put in wrong password, it says Wrong Password.  I am not asking for any special permissions that are not default.  Why would it just go back to the login dialog each time?  Help?